# How to use only the first long/short signal before the condition changes?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My arrow indicator (pine script v5) uses 2 conditions that can be repeated:

```
upArrow = up_sequence[1] and upDot[1] and not downDot[1] and not down_sequence[2] and filterLong
downArrow = down_sequence[1] and downDot[1] and not upDot[1] and not up_sequence[2] and filterShort
anyArrow = upArrow or downArrow

plotchar(upArrow, "", "↑", location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotchar(downArrow, "", "↓", location.abovebar, size=size.small)
alertcondition(upArrow, "Long", "GoLong")
alertcondition(downArrow, "Short", "GoShort")
alertcondition(anyArrow, "Any direction", "GoAnywhere")
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImd3.png)

How can I filter out the next signals after the first one before the condition changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `var` variable to see the last signal and print another arrow only if the last signal was not the same direction.

```
var is_up = false
var is_down = false

upArrow = not is_up and up_sequence[1] and upDot[1] and not downDot[1] and not down_sequence[2] and filterLong
downArrow = not is_down and down_sequence[1] and downDot[1] and not upDot[1] and not up_sequence[2] and filterShort

// Reset the flag on opposite signal. Set the flag if it is a new signal. Keep its value otherwise
is_up := downArrow ? false : upArrow ? true : is_up
is_down := upArrow ? false : downArrow ? true : is_down
```